# Format Pandas columns with thousand space separator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting, separator

I tried to look everywhere, but there is no exact answer to what I'm looking for.

I know the standard formatting for a thousand is with a comma, but I want a space as a thousand separator.
I tried this solution, but there is still the comma as a separator:

```
d = {'col1': [1000, 20000], 'col2': [300000, 400000]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
df['col1']=df['col1'].map('{:,.0f}'.format)
df['col1'].astype(str)
df['col1'].replace(',',' ',inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the work done to the variable, for example `df['col1'].astype('str')` needs to be assigned to `df['col1']`

Try this

```
d = {'col1': [1000, 20000], 'col2': [300000, 400000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].map('{:,.0f}'.format)
    df[col] = df[col].astype('str')
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(',',' ')
print(df)
```

output

```
     col1     col2
0   1 000  300 000
1  20 000  400 000
```